# URL of webservice Get return Null Parameter

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I'm using spring MVC to build a simple WebService

This are my classes

1 - Interface

```
import org.compiere.framework.VO;

    import com.audaxis.compiere.api.CompiereAPIApplicationException;
    import com.audaxis.erp.service.IBaseService;

    public interface IADTabService extends IBaseService  {

        public VO read(String window_ID, String tab_ID) throws CompiereAPIApplicationException;

    }
```

2 - Controller

```
@Controller
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Api(tags="AD")
public class ADTabWs extends BaseWs<IADTabService> {

    @RequestMapping(value="/Tab/window/{window}/tab/{tab}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody VO read(@PathVariable String window, String tab, @RequestHeader(value="X-SessionId", required=false) String session_id) 
            throws CompiereAPIApplicationException  {
        //@RequestHeader("X-SessionId") 
        return service.read(window, tab);
    }

}
```

Now , i'm using Jason to test my webservice

- WS URL :
  http://localhost:4080/ws/Tab/window/143/tab/186?=null&%20REQUEST%20HEADER%20=null&X-SessionId=1159871
- Méthode : GET

[image]

Problem:

- Parameter window_ID = 143  --> OK
- parameter tab_ID = `NULL` --> KO

[image]

AND This is the log :

```
2018-04-04 15:38:28.897 INFO  c.a.compiere.service.ad.ADTabService - 143 - null
```

I can't find the problem !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit your function like below:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Tab/window/{window}/tab/{tab}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody VO read(@PathVariable String window, @PathVariable String tab, @RequestHeader(value="X-SessionId", required=false) String session_id) 
        throws CompiereAPIApplicationException  {
    //@RequestHeader("X-SessionId") 
    return service.read(window, tab);
}
```

`@PathVariable` was missing from the `String tab` parameter.

Comment: i taught i accepted yesterday, so it's a correct answer, and i integrated in my code, thanks